# How to enter multiple email addresses in the Bcc property of the MailItem object?

Tags: vba, outlook

My VBA Code sends automatic email. How to fill more then one email address?

User creates new email and fill:
To: one email address
Bcc: email address2, email address3, email address4, ...

How does Outlook separate each email address in the Bcc property to send in my example 4 emails instead of one.

```
Dim strWho As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim objNewMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objNewMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strWho = objMail.To
strSubject = objMail.Subject 

With objNewMail
    .To = strWho
    .BCC = "mail2,mail3,mail4,mail5"
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Display
    .Send
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the semicolon `;` to separate each mail address, following this format:

```
"person1@email.com;person2@email.com"
```

If you have them already typed into the mail object, you can use this code:

```
Dim strWho As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim objNewMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim bccMails As String

Set objNewMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strWho = objMail.To
strSubject = objMail.Subject 
bccMails = objMail.BCC    

With objNewMail
    .To = strWho
    .BCC = bccMails
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Display
    .Send
End With
```

Otherwise you can ask the user once for the mail addresses with an `InputBox` and then using that value for every mail:

```
Dim bccMails As String
bccMails = InputBox("Please insert .bcc email addresses, separated by semicolons", "Email Address", "person1@email.com;person2@email.com")
```

Hope this helps as a starting point.

Comment: thank you for the advice, but emails isnt be same everytime, need to use .Bcc what type user when creating new email

Comment: Ok, to achieve this I can think of two ways: writing the mail addresses in a cell or using an InputBox. I will post some example in my answer

Comment: Writing them in a cell - call "Object required" error 424

Comment: @novice Your sheet name should be the same as the one you see on the left on "Microsoft Excel Objects" and you have to define the `range` in the `Excel Sheet`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: sorry now im totaly lost,i thought we are in outlook, not in excel

Comment: @novice Sorry I tought you were launching outlook from Excel (as many people do). In this case ignore the cell way.

Comment: Well, isnt there any other way how to do that ? becouse emails are alredy typed in .cc and .bcc, not necessary typed them again to imput box.

Comment: I think there is. Give me some minutes and I'll check it out

Comment: @novice I can't provide a more precise solution because you didn't provide your full code, but you can easily adapt this answer to your needs. :)